# How to persist prev.data in localStorage when adding new data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, local-storage

I added "select all" checkbox to my table, and I'm saving the data in localStorage to use it in other components. I'm able to save data and get it from localstorage when box is checked, also if user unchecks box, data gets removed from localstorage.  The problem is that after I uncheck "select all" checkbox I need to remove the data that was stored in localStorage when user clicked "select all" checkbox but all data from local storage gets deleted.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const peopleInfo = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Jane",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: "25"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "James",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: "40"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "Alexa",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: "27"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    name: "Jane",
    lastName: "Brown",
    age: "40"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [peopleInfoValue, setPeopleInfoValue] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const sp = localStorage.getItem("selectedPeople");
    if (sp) setPeopleInfoValue(JSON.parse(sp));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("selectedPeople", JSON.stringify(peopleInfoValue));
  }, [peopleInfoValue]);

  const handleSelect = (e, id) => {
    let checked = e.target.checked;

    if (checked) {
      setPeopleInfoValue(
        peopleInfo?.map((d) => {
          return {
            select: true,
            id: d.id,
            first: d.first,
            last: d.last,
            age: d.age
          };
        })
      );
    } else {
      setPeopleInfoValue([]);
    }
  };
  function toggle(e, id) {
    let checked = e.target.checked;
    if (checked) {
      setPeopleInfoValue([
        ...peopleInfoValue,
        {
          ...peopleInfo.find((pi) => pi.id === id),
          select: true
        }
      ]);
    } else {
      // to remove from localstorage
      setPeopleInfoValue(peopleInfoValue.filter((people) => people.id !== id));
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <input
            style={{ margin: "20px" }}
            onChange={(e) => handleSelect(e)}
            checked={peopleInfoValue.length == `${peopleInfo?.length}`}
            type="checkbox"
          />
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {peopleInfo?.map((d) => {
            const match = peopleInfoValue.find((piv) => piv.id === d.id);
            return (
              <tr key={d.id}>
                <td>
                  <input
                    style={{ margin: "20px" }}
                    onChange={(e) => toggle(e, d.id)}
                    checked={!!match?.select}
                    type="checkbox"
                  />
                </td>
                <td style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{d.name}</td>
                <td style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{d.lastName}</td>
                <td style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{d.age}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-bush-fw7rm?file=/src/App.js:23-2630)

In my code I use  setPeopleInfoValue([]) to delete data from localstorage when user clicks uncheck "select all" checkbox, and because of that all previously saved data in localstorage gets removed too. I can't figure out how to save/remove data received only from "select all" checkbox in localstorage and still keep previously saved data, for ex.if user selected 1st row and went to another page, and that 1st row will be displayed there(from localStorage), but if user comes back, checks and then unchecks "select all" box, previously saved 1st row will be removed also. How can I prevent that? I also need to keep displaying checked if boxes were checked on page refresh. Any suggestions and help are greatly appreciated.

Comment: So are you saying that the "select all" shouldn't also be a "deselect all" toggle? Why not treat it as just another toggle and derive the "all selected" "state" in the UI?

Comment: @Drew Reese, no, I want it to deselect all, but not to remove previously saved data in local storage. If user selected checkbox for 2nd row, and that data was saved in local storage, and if user comes back and selects and then deselects "select all", the 2nd row info will be also deleted. I don't know how to display data from separately selected rows and the data from check all in a way, that data doesn't get duplicated. So if user selects 1st row, and then select all, I don't want to have two 1st rows, and also if user selects all and then deselects it, I still want to display prev. 1st row

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The main issue is that your "all selected" state overwrites any history or sense of what was previously set.

## Solution

I suggest storing the "all selected" state separately in the component, and separately persist it to local storage as well. You can derive the "all selected" state from this state. In other words, the rest of the selectable/toggleable values checked state is either their checked state ***OR*** the the "all selected" state.

```
export default function App() {
  const [peopleInfoValue, setPeopleInfoValue] = useState([]);
  const [allSelected, setAllSelected] = useState(false); // added "allSelected" state

  useEffect(() => {
    const sp = localStorage.getItem("selectedPeople");
    if (sp) setPeopleInfoValue(JSON.parse(sp));

    const allSelect = localStorage.getItem("allSelected");
    setAllSelected(JSON.parse(allSelect)); // initialize from local storage
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("selectedPeople", JSON.stringify(peopleInfoValue));
  }, [peopleInfoValue]);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("allSelected", JSON.stringify(allSelected));
  }, [allSelected]); // persist to local storage

  const handleSelect = (e) => {
    const { checked } = e.target;
    setAllSelected(checked); // set the all selected toggle state
  };

  function toggle(e, id) {
    let checked = e.target.checked;
    if (checked) {
      setPeopleInfoValue([
        ...peopleInfoValue,
        {
          ...peopleInfo.find((pi) => pi.id === id),
          select: true
        }
      ]);
    } else {
      // to remove from localstorage
      setPeopleInfoValue(peopleInfoValue.filter((people) => people.id !== id));
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <input
            style={{ margin: "20px" }}
            onChange={handleSelect}
            checked={allSelected}
            type="checkbox"
          />
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {peopleInfo?.map((d) => {
            const match = peopleInfoValue.find((piv) => piv.id === d.id);
            return (
              <tr key={d.id}>
                <td>
                  <input
                    style={{ margin: "20px" }}
                    onChange={(e) => toggle(e, d.id)}
                    checked={!!match?.select || allSelected} // set derived checked state
                    type="checkbox"
                  />
                </td>
                <td style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{d.name}</td>
                <td style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{d.lastName}</td>
                <td style={{ margin: "20px" }}>{d.age}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit how-to-persist-prev-data-in-localstorage-when-adding-new-data]

***Note:** I don't know what you want the behavior to be once "select all" is selected and a user then deselects a person, but you should probably gracefully de-select the "select all" option at this point. Should all previously "all selected" values remain selected? Should they also revert back to their original state. This is a rat hole of what-ifs and hows.*

Comment: But when I click "select all" info from all rows doesn't get added to localstorage.  In my example from codesandbox, checkbox works the way I want, when user clicks select all ,data from every row gets added to localstorage, when user deselects for ex.1st row, remaining rows are still in localstorage.The problem I'm having is that if user selects 1st row, goes to another page, then comes back and clicks select all( although previously added row is still in local storage), if user clicks deselect all that 1st row gets deleted also. I want user to see 1st row even if he deselects all afterwards.

Comment: @nika It is added to localStorage, but again, it's technically derived state. And well, to be perfectly honest, the behavior you describe wanting doesn't make any sense. If at anytime you select all, or deselect all, and all items are selected, or deselected, what else can it do? Sounds like you want more of an undo/redo if you want to uncheck "select all" and have your UI/localStorage "remember" and restore a previous state.